# Dependent excel list doesn't change when the main list item changes

Tags: excel, dropdown

As an MS-Excel beginner, I have created a 'dependent drop-down list' by data validation, using the below formula.

```
OFFSET($A$1,1,MATCH($A11,$A$1:$D$1,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET($A$1,1,MATCH($A11,$A$1:$D$1,0)-1,7,1)),1)
```

Now the problem is that when the selected item in the main list is changed, the dependent list still shows the previous items, and not showing any error until I go and click the drop-down menu to select from.
This may cause mistakes.
Is there any solution, preferably by not using VBA?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot or provide the table?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that without VBA.  Probably with `Worksheet_change` event code; where you check to see if the contents of your dependent drop down are in the list called for by the parent drop down.